# Apache Kafka Benchmeark Configurations based on input records

Tags: apache-kafka

I am Using Apache  Kafka in my project With Default configurations. I want to change the configurations. based on input records. I didn't get proper documentation to change According to the publishing records.

```
In my case i have 300 msgs/sec. I am using 3 node Kafka cluster and replication factor 3 and partitions 10 for each topic.
```

Comment: What's the question? Kafka should be configured based on the scale requirement and availability.

Comment: those are Default configurations, right? please correct me if am wrong

Comment: There are default configs, but you can override them with ease. What's your requirement? What do you mean by "...based on input records"?

Comment: Actually We are IoT based. We have sensors data. Most of the time we will get max 300 records/sec we got. and we published it to Kafka. For some time. if we send data continuously we lost data in the consumer Application. that's why I am planning to change the producer server and consumer configurations. as per input records

Comment: You could tune the retries, in-flight requests, and the acks settings which would guarantee records are written at the cost of speed... Not sure what that has to do with benchmarking or how many records you actually send

Comment: Yes, I would tune these params: 1. Acks. 2. Max in flight. 3. No. of partitions. etc.